# SQL server connection TCP/IP overt Ethernet

Tags: tcp, sql, ethernet

I have two PCs. There is SQL Express installed on one of them. TCP/IP settins are here:

tcp/ip settings
[image: tcp/ip settings]

tcp/ip settings
[image: tcp/ip settings]

When I perform Test-NetConnection on local computer I get
[image: local]

But when I do it from remote PC I get
[image: remote]

As you can see tcp succeeds when connected over WiFi but fails over Ethernet. Ping is OK but TCP/IP connection fails. I tried many different ports with same results. I'd be grateful for any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the Windows Firewall is enabled on the SQL Server and you haven't defined an inbound rule that allows inbound TCP to your desired port. Take a look at that.